# When IDs are identical check that the Ordinal is greater than the previous submission

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Example query**

```
USE HES 
SELECT T1.ID, T2.DATE, T1.ORDINAL
FROM TABLE1 AS T1   
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS T2  
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.PARTYEAR = T2.PARTYEAR  
WHERE
    T1.MONTHYEAR = '201501'
```

**Results from example query**

```
ID  Date    Ordinal

1   01/01/2016  1
1   02/01/2016  2
1   03/01/2016  3
2   04/01/2016  1
2   05/01/2016  2
3   06/01/2016  1
3   07/01/2016  2
3   08/01/2016  3    
4   09/01/2016  1
4   10/01/2016  1
```

**Question**

Each user has a unique ID, for each ID how would I to check that each data submission contains an Ordinal that is greater than the one that was previously submitted.

So, in the example query results above, ID 4 contains an issue.

I'm fairly new to SQL, I've been searching for similar examples but with no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Anything you've tried so far and is not working?

Comment: so the output would be 4

Comment: Hope you are on 2012+ , use lead/lag

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012. I've played around and used the very basics but I'm honestly out of my depth at the moment.

Comment: Yes, the output would preferably be the ID and the Date. Also, in the query, partyear and monthyear are the same thing, I accidentally gave them different names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) with OVER clause:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT T1.ID, T2.DATE, T1.ORDINAL, LAG(T1.ORDINAL) OVER(PARTITION BY T1.ID ORDER BY T1.ORDINAL) AS LagOrdinal
    FROM TABLE1 AS T1   
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS T2  
        ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.PARTYEAR = T2.PARTYEAR  
    WHERE
        T1.MONTHYEAR = '201501'
)
SELECT ID, DATE, ORDINAL, CASE WHEN ORDINAL > LagOrdinal THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OrdinalIsGreater
    FROM cte;
```

Comment: I was able to update this easily and it seems to be working perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Like @Serg said, you can achieve this using `lag`

```
select *
   from (
    SELECT T1.ID, T2.DATE, T1.ORDINAL, 
           lag(t1.ordinal) over (partition by t1.id order by t2.date) as prevOrdinal
    FROM TABLE1 AS T1   
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS T2  
        ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.PARTYEAR = T2.PARTYEAR  
    WHERE
        T1.MONTHYEAR = '201501') as t
  where t.prevOrdinal >= t.ordinal;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ID  DATE       ORDINAL  prevOrdinal
4   2016-10-01  1       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * INTO #tmp
FROM (VALUES    
(1, CONVERT(date, '01/01/2016'), 1),
(1, '02/01/2016', 2),
(1, '03/01/2016', 3),
(2, '04/01/2016', 1),
(2, '05/01/2016', 2),
(3, '06/01/2016', 1),
(3, '07/01/2016', 2),
(3, '08/01/2016', 3),   
(4, '09/01/2016', 1),
(4, '10/01/2016', 1)
)T(ID, Date, Ordinal)

WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) R, *
    FROM #tmp
)
SELECT N2.ID, N2.Date, N1.Ordinal Prev, N2.Ordinal Curr
FROM Numbered N1
JOIN Numbered N2 ON N1.R+1=N2.R AND N1.ID=N2.ID
WHERE N1.Ordinal >= N2.Ordinal
```

It can be simplified when SQL Server version >= 2012, `#tmp` is your current result.